# Unable to bind IFormFile input parameter from Node app

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core

I am submitting a request to my web api which is used to upload a file.

This is the signature of my API.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("abc/uploadFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
   
}
```

This is how I am submitting the request.

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

public async uploadFile2 (filePath: string): Promise<any> {
    let path = `http://localhost:3000/abc/uploadFile`;
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath)); 
    
    const uploadResponse = await fetch(path, {method: 'POST', body: form, headers: form.getHeaders() });

    return uploadResponse;
}
```

This is how the form looks like after logging it on the console.

```
{
    "_overheadLength": 298,
    "_valueLength": 10,
    "_valuesToMeasure": [
        {
            "fd": null,
            "path": "./test.txt",
            "flags": "r",
            "mode": 438,
            "end": null,
            "bytesRead": 0,
            "_readableState": {
                "objectMode": false,
                "highWaterMark": 65536,
                "buffer": {
                    "head": null,
                    "tail": null,
                    "length": 0
                },
                "length": 0,
                "pipes": [],
                "flowing": false,
                "ended": false,
                "endEmitted": false,
                "reading": false,
                "constructed": false,
                "sync": true,
                "needReadable": false,
                "emittedReadable": false,
                "readableListening": false,
                "resumeScheduled": false,
                "errorEmitted": false,
                "emitClose": true,
                "autoDestroy": true,
                "destroyed": false,
                "errored": null,
                "closed": false,
                "closeEmitted": false,
                "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                "awaitDrainWriters": null,
                "multiAwaitDrain": false,
                "readingMore": false,
                "dataEmitted": false,
                "decoder": null,
                "encoding": null
            },
            "_events": {},
            "_eventsCount": 3
        }
    ],
    "writable": false,
    "readable": true,
    "dataSize": 0,
    "maxDataSize": 2097152,
    "pauseStreams": true,
    "_released": false,
    "_streams": [
        "----------------------------435334925135376500544808\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_buffer\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n",
        {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        null,
        "----------------------------435334925135376500544808\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n",
        {
            "source": {
                "fd": null,
                "path": "./test.txt",
                "flags": "r",
                "mode": 438,
                "end": null,
                "bytesRead": 0,
                "_readableState": {
                    "objectMode": false,
                    "highWaterMark": 65536,
                    "buffer": {
                        "head": null,
                        "tail": null,
                        "length": 0
                    },
                    "length": 0,
                    "pipes": [],
                    "flowing": false,
                    "ended": false,
                    "endEmitted": false,
                    "reading": false,
                    "constructed": false,
                    "sync": true,
                    "needReadable": false,
                    "emittedReadable": false,
                    "readableListening": false,
                    "resumeScheduled": false,
                    "errorEmitted": false,
                    "emitClose": true,
                    "autoDestroy": true,
                    "destroyed": false,
                    "errored": null,
                    "closed": false,
                    "closeEmitted": false,
                    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                    "awaitDrainWriters": null,
                    "multiAwaitDrain": false,
                    "readingMore": false,
                    "dataEmitted": false,
                    "decoder": null,
                    "encoding": null
                },
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 3
            },
            "dataSize": 0,
            "maxDataSize": null,
            "pauseStream": true,
            "_maxDataSizeExceeded": false,
            "_released": false,
            "_bufferedEvents": [
                {
                    "0": "pause"
                }
            ],
            "_events": {},
            "_eventsCount": 1
        },
        null
    ],
    "_currentStream": null,
    "_insideLoop": false,
    "_pendingNext": false,
    "_boundary": "--------------------------435334925135376500544808"
}
```

When this request is getting submitted to the action result the `file` input parameter is coming as null.

When I try to inspect the `HttpContext.Request.Form` object then I am getting an error.

Error Message: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.

StackTrace:

```
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.<ReadNextSectionAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.<InnerReadFormAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
```

I don't get any error when I invoke this API from Postman app.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems some actions could cause this error, here is a discussion in [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18087) about this issue.